# Process each frame of camera in real time?

Tags: react-native

I'm making a React Native app that includes a scanning feature. I need to scan these documents that follow a certain format, and to do so I need to process each frame of the camera feed.

Is this possible in React Native? Is there something I can use to have a live camera feed and process it frame by frame?

Comment: Hi there! I think it would be better if the title of your question concentrated on what you want to achieve: scanning barcodes. Processing video frames would be a way to do it, but that's not the end result you want, what you want are barcodes.

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with Expo you can use their `BarCodeScanner` component. You can find he docs [here](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/bar-code-scanner/#supported-formats). It supports a lot of different formats of barcodes.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to explore [`Frame Processors`](https://github.com/mrousavy/react-native-vision-camera) from the [react-native-vision-camera](https://mrousavy.com/react-native-vision-camera/docs/guides/frame-processors) library. Frame processors lets you write custom code that process frames the camera "sees".

If your question is about scanning barcodes, you can try the [vision-camera-dynamsoft-barcode-reader](https://github.com/tony-xlh/vision-camera-dynamsoft-barcode-reader) frame processor plugin. Or you can explore other [community built frame processor plugins](https://mrousavy.com/react-native-vision-camera/docs/guides/frame-processor-plugin-list#plugin-list).